# Implications between $K$ field and $K[x]$ PID and ED

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, euclidean-domain

I know that if $K$ is a field, then $K[x]$ is an ED (Euclidean Domain), and that if $K[x]$ is a PID (Principal Ideal Domain) then $K$ is a field. Now, I can say that if $K[x]$ is an ED, then it is a PID, therefore $K$ is a field. Similarly, if $K$ is a field, then $K[x]$ it is an ED, therefore it is a PID. So basically I have that:

- (1) $K$ is a field $\Longleftrightarrow$ $K[x]$ is an ED
- (2) $K$ is a field $\Longleftrightarrow$ $K[x]$ is a PID

Putting these two things togheter I have that:

$K[x]$ is an ED $\Longleftrightarrow$ $K$ is a field $\Longleftrightarrow$ $K[x]$ is a PID

This brings to: $K[x]$ is an ED $\Longleftrightarrow$ $K[x]$ is a PID, which is obviously absurd.

I thought about possible mistakes in this argument, and the only explanation that I gave myself is that I used a sort of a circular argument, since to prove ($\Longleftarrow$) in (1) I used ($\Longleftarrow$) in (2), and to prove ($\Longrightarrow$) in (2) I used ($\Longrightarrow$) in (1). In conclusion, (1) and (2) are valid (it does make sense also because ED implies PID, so all the properties of a PID are also properties of an ED), while putting the implications together isn't.

Is that so? If yes, why? And if not, what is the problem?

Comment: ($\implies$) in (1) and (2) are true but not sure if the converse should hold.

Comment: The answer of silvascientist in this question gives a proof that $K[x]$ PID implies $K$ field: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011161/is-it-true-that-f-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-fx-is-an-euclidean-domain

Comment: I guess the statement $K[x]$ PID iff $K[x]$ ED is a statement on polynomial rings and not arbitrary rings so there's no clear contradiction at first sight.

Comment: I hadn't thought in this way, but I guess that maybe a statement true for polynomial rings is not automatically true also for arbitrary rings..